Manga where the reincarnated female protagonist leaves the family where she is hated and joins a mafia
I remember seeing a story about a girl who gets reincarnated into a fantasy world and she is the hated daughter of the family and the villainess. she then leaves the family and joins a mafia, eventually ending up as the head of the mafia.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it in colour or black-and-white?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?

This is likely All Hail Lady Blanche!. It is licensed by Pocket Comics.

To Blanche, everything seemed hopeless. Until she realized it was all a game. One she made, to be exact. Now she has a goal: Become the villain's right-hand man! But wait. Why is she the one saving him...?

It's not mentioned in this synopsis but it is an isekai story. The protagonist reincarnates in the world of a game she created.
This previous question mentions that she joins a gang and becomes queen.
Blanche in the story is definitely hated by her family and at the start of the story is offered as a bride to an unpleasant man in place of her beloved sister.
